# PM2, 502 Bad gateway, Nginx serving both React app and NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, http-status-code-502

I'm serving both React app and NodeJS API with Nginx configuration (from Nginx `sites-available` folder):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name my-site-name.com www.my-site-name.com;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

If I start the NodeJS API on the server with `npm start`- everything works. If I run the API as a process with PM2 - I get 502 Bad gateway by calling any API endpoint.

EDIT: PM2 doesn't serve app at expected port (3000). Found out by turning it off.

Comment: After `npm run build` is your files located in `var/www/html` or `var/www/html/your_build_folder` ?

Comment: I tried it both ways, in both scenarios - static part of React app is working (with additional change in nginx config, of course). Only API part isn't working

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was not serving the app at expected port (3000).

The problem was in my `server.js` file which I ran by `pm2 start server.js`. I saw many suggestions online to start NodeJS app with `pm2 start ./bin/www` command. You can do this if your Express NodeJS project is initialized by [Express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).

My project wasn't initialized by Express generator, so I created a dummy project to see content of `./bin/www` file.

```
> mkdir my-app
> cd my-app
> npx express-generator
```

Then I copied content of `www` file which is located in `bin` directory to my `server.js` file. Only change was in line 7:

```
var app = require('../app');
```

I changed it to

```
var app = require('./app');
```

Because both `server.js` and `app.js` files are located in my project root.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issues while setting up my staging server. [Posted a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685923/nginx-conf-for-nodejs-react-app-returning-502-and-405/70701588#70701588)

Few things that worked for me:

- Using try/catch loops wherever you missed them in your server side code
- Making sure all environment variables are properly being read
- Check pm2 logs for node errors
- Check nginx logs for configuration faults