# nginx.conf for NodeJS/React App returning 502 and 405

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy, configuration

Trying to setup a staging environment on Amazon LINUX EC2 instance and migrate from Heroku.
My repository has two folders:

- Web
- API

**Our frontend and backend are running on the same port in deployment**

In **dev**, these are run on separate ports and all requests from WEB and proxied to API
(for ex. WEB runs on PORT 3000 and API runs on PORT 3001. Have a proxy set up in the *package.json* file in WEB/)

Currently the application deployment works like this:

- Build Web/ for distribution
- Copy build/ to API folder
- Deploy to Heroku with `web npm start`

In **prod**, we only deploy API folder with the WEB build/

Current nginx.conf looks like this
[Commented out all other attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guxro.png)

Also using PM2 to run the thread like so
`$ sudo pm2 bin/www`
Current thread running like so:
[pm2 log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMjok.png)
This is running on PORT 3000 on the EC2 instance

Going to the public IPv4 DNS for instance brings me to the login, which it's getting from the /build folder but none of the login methods (or any API calls) are working.
[502 response example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWWQT.png)

I have tried a lot of different configurations. Set up the proxy_pass to port 3000 since thats where the Node process is running.
The only response codes I get are **405 Not Allowed** and **502 Bad Gateway**

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an issue with express-sessions being stored in Postgres.
This led me to retest the connection strings and I found out that I kept receiving the following error:

`connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`

I did have a .env file holding the env variables and they were not being read by pm2.
So I added this line to app.js:

```
const path = require("path");
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '.env') });
```

then restarted the app with pm2 with the following command:

`$ pm2 restart /bin/www --update-env`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have an upstream block in your configuration. Looks like you're trying to use `proxy-pass` to send to a named server and port instead of a defined upstream. There's is an example on this page that shows how you define the upstream and then send traffic to it. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

`````
    server backend1.example.com       weight=5;
    server backend2.example.com:8080;
    server unix:/tmp/backend3;
    server backup1.example.com:8080   backup;
    server backup2.example.com:8080   backup;
}
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}````
`````